# Data format for mixed modelling in R

Tags: r, mixed-model

This isn't a question about the theoretical underpinnings of mixed modeling, it is more about how dependant variable should be entered into a dataset to successfully run a model.

I have recently finished running a linear mixed model in R and am now attempting to run a second model using a different outcome variable. Previously I examined the impact on participant reaction times through a series of factors. My data was in a long format where each row was a trial from a computerized task. Hence each trial had an associated reaction time where participants completed a task and each participant had many rows showing their reaction time by trial in the dataset. It was the trial reaction time column I used as my dependant variable.

However, the dependant variable I am looking at now is somewhat different and I am not sure if the same principles carry over. Let's call the new dependant variable the number of accidental button presses. It is still numerically continuous, but in a trial, a participant can either accidentally press a button (scoring 1) or not (scoring 0). Therefore while a participant could have for example 10 accidental button presses in total from the computerized task, on a single trial they ether score a 1 or a 0. This means that when I look at a histogram of the accidental button press variable where each trial is a row it appears dichotomous and not like a normal distribution.

This makes me wonder if the data should be entered into a different format to run a linear mixed model. I don't think totaling the accidental button press for each participant is quite correct because the mixed model is losing the variability between trials. Also by aggregating into a single number per participant I don't think the model would run as the number of observations would equal the number of participants. Yet it is the *total number of button presses* that I want to compare between participants.

The only other option I have is that I do have a column for cumulative accidental button presses. By row for each participant, this increases in count as accidental button presses occur. For a single participant, it looks like 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3 … etc. I am wondering if I should be trying to analyze this, however, it doesn't feel quite right.

Thoughts for a stats dummy? Thanks.

Comment: "in a trial a participant can either accidently press a button (scoring 1) or not (scoring 0)." I don't understand the experimental setup. Was the participant guaranteed to press a button? Or is there a hidden third outcome "no button pressed"? Right now I would suggest using your scores as response variable in a binomial GLMM. This will give you a probability of a participant accidentally pressing a button and that could be multiplied with the number of tries.

Comment: @Roland I should clarify that participants were guaranteed to press the button, but it is the number of times that the button was pressed too early which is being examined.

Comment: OK, then my suggestion applies.